# Displaying live graph in google glass

Tags: google-glass, google-api-java-client, android-graphview

I'm searching for a way to display live data in a graph using google glass. According to "supported google APIs" there are no APIs currently supporting this feature.

I have also taken a look at the android graphview API but without any luck.

Are there any known APIs that work or is an JavaScript implementation a possible way to implement this feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently not built-in Widget to display graphs on Android.
Luckily enough, there is a thing called [LiveCard](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/live-cards) on Google Glass to display realtime information.
You can then, with a little work draw the realtime graph on your own and render it to the LiveCard's remoteview.
If you need an example, [here is an open source app](https://github.com/ConceptSafetySystems/GlassTempMonitor) that displays the temperature in realtime.

Comment: I did after some work get it to work with android graph view so that seems to be a solution at this moment.